# Nodes won't join cluster : NotMasterException (Weird master election bug)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm setting up an elasticsearch (5.0.1) cluster.

It has three master-eligible nodes :

```
el-m01
el-m02
el-m03
```

The cluster fails to assemble, and Every master node gets the following `NotMasterException` exception in the logs :

```
[2016-11-21T15:24:13,274][INFO ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [el-m01] failed to send join request to master [{el-m02}{bBhsu3fJSj-MyiWJGhQmog}{_IzdeUd4Sv6g-rhemGjEVQ}{192.168.110.118}{192.168.110.118:9300}{rack=r1}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[el-m02][192.168.110.118:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: NotMasterException[Node [{el-m02}{bBhsu3fJSj-MyiWJGhQmog}{_IzdeUd4Sv6g-rhemGjEVQ}{192.168.110.118}{192.168.110.118:9300}{rack=r1}] not master for join request]; ], tried [3] times
```

Enabling the debugging logs allowed me to understand the following :

The master election is happening, and is a success. However, while every node has chosen a master, no nodes thinks he is the master. 
i.e. :

- el-m01 thinks el-m02 is the master
- el-m02 thinks el-m03 is the master
- el-m03 thinks el-m01 is the master

What is happening here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the situation : By cloning a VM to get all the masters, every node has the **same node id**.

This can be verified with the following command, listing all nodes ids :

```
GET /_cat/nodes?v&h=id,ip,name&full_id=true
```

Note that since your cluster hasn't formed, each node needs to be queried individually, i.e :

```
curl 192.168.110.111:9200/_cat/nodes?v&h=id,ip,name&full_id=true
curl 192.168.110.112:9200/_cat/nodes?v&h=id,ip,name&full_id=true
(...)
```

This is bad. the node ids need to be unique.

To solve this situation, you need to delete the indices (in `/var/lib/elasticsearch`) on every node. This will ***delete all data in elasticsearch***, and will also reset the node ids.

To avoid having this problem in the first place, you can :

- A. install elasticsearch *after* having cloned the VMs
- B. use an automated tool like ansible or puppet to manage elasticsearch.

Comment: up vote for the solution. It solved my cluster forming after 6 days of effort. Thanks

Comment: the key point is to not start elasticsearch service on the server from which other vms / ec2 instances will be created.

Answer (score 1):

The Elasticsearch data directory `$ES_HOME/data`, or in the case of RPM, e.g., `/var/lib/elasticsearch` contains a randomly generated node ID when Elasticsearch is first started.   If this directory is copied to multiple instances that are expected to form a cluster, the following error should be received:

```
failed to send join request to master [..] IllegalArgumentException [..] found existing node [..] with the same id but is a different node instance
```

However, when `minimum_master_nodes` is not met, an error less indicative of the problem is received:

```
failed to send join request to master [..] NotMasterException [..] not master for join request
```

Github:  https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/32904

The issue can be resolved by deleting the contents of the data directory, and data directories shouldn't be copied in the first place.

Comment: just to be specific... `$/var/lib/elasticsearch# rm -rf nodes/`